# How do I use templating with Hibernate and Gradle?

Tags: java, hibernate, gradle

I have a server that talks to a database that I need to test. I connect to the database using Hibernate and manage the dependencies using Gradle. I want to use separate tables in MySql for production and testing. So I have currently this line in hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/production_database</property>
```

But what I really want is for it to be something like:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/${DATABASE_NAME}</property>
```

and then when I run `gradle test`, DATABASE_NAME can be set to "test_database_name", and when I run `gradle jettyRun` it'll still be "production_database". This seems like something that should be possible, but when I google for "hibernate teplating" I get references this other thing called HibernateTemplate that has nothing to do with what I want as far as I can tell. What's the syntax that'll make this happen for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move that property out of hibernate.cfg.xml, and into a database.properties file.

And, Then you can use gradle to modify this file depending upon the argument.

Please refer to Gradle Tasks for this.

```
ant.propertyfile(
        file: "database.properties") {
        entry( key: "connectionurl", value: "somevalue")
    }
```